# Majorana zero modes in p-wave superconductors

Tags: superconductivity, majorana-fermions

I am trying to understand in an intuitive way why there is a zero mode in 2D p-wave superconductor with vortices (or in a similar model of He-A). Reading the paper by Misirpashaev, T. Sh, and G. E. Volovik. "Fermion zero modes in symmetric vortices in superfluid He$_3$",  Physica B: Condensed Matter 210.3-4 (1995): 338-346. The idea is also described in Volovik's book "The Universe in a Helium Droplet". The main idea is to prove that the eigenfunctions correspond to integer angular momentum $Q$ in the case of p wave pairing. Then for the states with zero angular momentum energy is zero, as E[Q]=-E[-Q] due to particle-hole symmetry.

In case of s-wave superconductor with vortex such operator is given by $\hat{Q}_s=\hat{L}_z-(m/2)\hat{I}$, where $m$ -- is the winding number of the order parameter, $\Delta(\vec{r})=\Delta(|\vec{r}|)e^{im\phi}$,  where $\phi$ -- is the polar angle. $\hat{L}_z= -i \partial/\partial \phi$. So the eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian are the eigenfunctions of this operator. The eigenvalues of $\hat{Q}_s$ are half-integers in case if $m$ is odd - in that case there are no zero modes.

In p-wave superconductors, according to Misirpashaev and Volovik,  this operator $\hat{Q}_p=\hat{L}_z-\frac{m+1}{2}\hat{I} $ (it is the Eq. 3.2 in the paper). And I don't really get where does this additional $1/2$ comes from (i.e. $m+1$ instead of $m$). In the paper they argue that this is due to spin of the state. I don't really see where it comes from? Or is there probably more clear way to see why vortices in p-wave superconductors are so special?